# PageViewController with multiple ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Basically I'd like the landing page of my app to have a different layout than the page content views of my page view controller. I'm having trouble setting the starting view controller to be my landing page.

Here is the code where I initialize the pageViewController

```
// Creating the onboarding data
_pageCaptions = @[@"",@"How we do it",@"What we plan to do"];
_pageImages = @[@"Landing.png", @"OnboardingHolder1.png", @"OnboardingHolder2.png"];

// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

GOVPageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
NSLog(@"%@", viewControllers[0]);


[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 75, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100);

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Here is the code where the navigation between view controllers is handled:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[LandingContentViewController class]]) {
    return nil;
} else {

    NSUInteger index = ((GOVPageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == 0) {
        LandingContentViewController *landing = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandingContentViewController"];
        return landing;
    }

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {


if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[LandingContentViewController class]]) {
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

} else {
    NSUInteger index = ((GOVPageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageCaptions count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}}

- (GOVPageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (([self.pageCaptions count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageCaptions count])) {
    return nil;
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
GOVPageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
pageContentViewController.captionText = self.pageCaptions[index];
pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

return pageContentViewController;}
```

As the code is, the first view that I'm presented with in simulator is the first of the "GOVPageContentViewControllers." I am able to swipe to the right over this page view in order to reveal the landing page properly. This is understandable because I set the startingViewController to be the first of the GOVPageContentViewController.

How do I properly add the LandingContentViewController to be the first viewController that I use to setViewControllers with?

Answer (score 0):

You should present the viewController instead of view.
Use following code:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:_pageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];  
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];  
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: The pageViewController is a subview of the root view controller. I'd like to have the first page view a different view controller than the rest of the page views.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two choices:

1. Present your "landing" view controller, then have it (via button or timer or whatever) present your PageViewController.
2. Present your PageViewController, and set an instance of your "landing" page as the first page-content view controller. (There's no reason you can't do this. Your page-content view controllers don't have to all be the same type.)

With #1, once PageViewController is presented it consists of only page-content items.

With #2, your PageViewController presents both the landing page and other pages as content items. If you don't want the landing page to ever appear after user scrolls off of it, just adjust your VC-before/VC-after functions to just omit it when scrolling "back".

Comment: Note that the code you posted shows nothing about your "landing" view controller, so I'm inferring a bit here.

Comment: To clarify: the landing view controller only consists of three text labels while the page content view controller would consist of a text label and an image. With #2, are you saying that I can handle the code for a unique first page content view within the GOVPageContentViewController?

Comment: I don't know what your GOVPageContentViewController is. You posted code fragments, but don't identify what class names you used for the classes that contain the code... So I have no idea how to answer your question. What I'm saying is that you have a PageViewController that presents individual pages (themselves ViewControllers) of content, and that there's no reason your first "page" of content can't be whatever view controller you're using as your "landing" view controller. To give you any better answer you need to clarify your classes for Landing, page "Container" and Page content.